# Changing a picture background to transparent in word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

How do you change the background of a picture to transparent in word 2013? I have tried using the remove background button under the picture format tool but that did not work. i also tried several other options in the picture format toolbar and i was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

The office "remove background" tool is only good if the background is a very big contrast to the object.  Is it possible to remake the image with a different background?

Otherwise you may want to look into third party software like Photoshop or Gimp. Gimp is the free option by the way.  If these options don't seem to work for you then could you upload the image for us to see?

Comment: Paint.net is another good one that you can use to make parts of your image transparent. (It also supports layers, BTW.)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to convert it to a GIF and make the background transparent.  Depending on the picture, this might be really easy or really difficult.  For a free webapp that I've found handy in the past for this type of thing, try http://pixlr.com/.

Answer (score 0):

1. Increase the zoom percent so that you can see the graphic. Tap or click the color button (picture tools format tab[ adjust group) to display color gallery.
2. Tap or click 'set transparent color' in the color gallery to display a pen pointer in the window.
3. Tap or click the location in the graphic where you want to make the color transparent. -- If you make the wrong color transparent -- tap or click the undo button or press CTRL+Z and repeat these steps.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying to achieve a transparent picture in word 13 . Buy a cheap DTP like page plus X7 or later . Make a picture transparent there, its ever so easy, and copy paste to word. You may have to adjust resize the picture . Then you can add other adjustments to the picture in word like glow .

Answer (score 0):

Adding an image with a transparent background and setting it "in front of text" is the way I found to get what you need.
A white background is added if you insert an image without a background (Word 2019).
You need to use an image editor like Photoshop or GIMP to add a transparent background to your image before inserting it in Word.

Example: in any image editor can manage layers, you have to create a new transparent layer and merge it with the image layer as in the picture below:

(with Photoshop 2022: Layer>New>Layer.. (SHIFT+CTRL+N) for adding the new layer;
Layer>Merge Layers (CTRL+E) for merging it with the image one.)

[image]

When done, you may insert that image in a Word document; the final result is in the picture below:

[image]

You may see that the edge of the picture has no background and that the Layout Options is set to "In front of text".

Comment: Please avoid repeating a previous answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).